# Admob banner in the middle of toolbar

Tags: ios, swift

Is it possible to put admit banner in the middle of `navigationController.toolbar` ? Way I did it (inside `viewDidLoad`):

```
    let banner = GADBannerView(adSize: kGADAdSizeBanner)
    banner.adUnitID="ca-app-pub-123"
    banner.rootViewController=self
    banner.load(GADRequest())
    self.navigationController?.isToolbarHidden=false
    self.navigationController?.toolbar.addSubview(banner)
    self.navigationController?.toolbar.sizeToFit()
```

However banner is aligned to the left side of a toolbar. Is there a simple way to align banner to the middle?

Comment: To put it in middle you can set it in title view using :  `self.navigationItem.titleView = banner`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please add position for your banner

```
banner.frame.origin = CGPoint(x: self.navigationController?.toolbar.frame.width / 2 - banner.frame.width / 2, y: self.navigationController?.toolbar.frame.height / 2 - banner.frame.height / 2)
```